# Remove Route53 Entry after Instance Termination

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are using AWS and add the IP of an Instance at it's launch to a weighted Route53 Record Set. We would like to remove this record set on the event of the instance's termination.

I know about executing a script at  run-levels in linux which would enable me do this, also know about lifecycle hooks which can be applied on autoscaling groups. I was wondering if there is a simple instance-specific way to do this using AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a lambda function to be triggered via cloudwatch when a instance is terminated